# Staking contract without minting

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, contract-design, staking

I would like to create a staking contract for my token.

I found many examples of the staking contracts, but all of them were using a _burn and _mint token methods. Because I want my token to have a limited supply and be deflationary, I don’t want to use the _mint function because it will result in creating an additional supply.

Instead, I would like to distribute staking rewards from the tokens that will be sent to the staking contract once in a while. Is it something that is possible to create in solidity? Can you please refer example of such a staking contract or can you advise how to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A contract such as [staking rewards](https://github.com/Synthetixio/synthetix/blob/develop/contracts/StakingRewards.sol) from Synthetix is usually a good example

Comment: here is a simplified version of that contract https://solidity-by-example.org/defi/staking-rewards/